# NHibernate Linq - how to create a where statement with IS NOT NULL

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

how can i achieve this query with Nhibernate Linq?

```
var l = session.CreateQuery("from Auswahl a where a.Returnkey is not null").List<Auswahl>();
```

i tried this but it always returns an empty list.

```
var l = session.Linq<Auswahl>()
                   .Where(item => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Returnkey))
                   .Select(item => item)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var l = session.Linq<Auswahl>()
                   .Where(item => item.Returnkey != null && item.Returnkey != "")
                   .Select(item => item)
                   .ToList();
```

I'm not sure that using String.IsNullOrEmpty would work, also it checks for two conditions - if it's NULL and if it's a blank empty string, how would that get translated into SQL? Might be worth having a look at SQL Profiler to see the raw SQL query it generates.

Comment: thanks, you are right. but dont forget to write 

item.Returnkey != " " 

otherwise you get nothing from oracle. 
the Sql produced now looks like this:
 
SELECT this_.ID           as ID1_0_,
       this_.Programm     as Programm1_0_,
       this_.Variante     as Variante1_0_,
       this_.Returnkey    as Returnkey1_0_,
       this_.Beschreibung as Beschrei5_1_0_
FROM   AUSWAHL this_
WHERE  (this_.Returnkey is not null 
        and not (this_.Returnkey = ' ' /* :p0 */))
    
!there is a blank between ' ' :)

Comment: It's woth remembering that, for Oracle, null and the empty string are the same.